# Cannot read property 'map' of undefined in reducer

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I'm facing a common mistake. I have a list of emails and other values that I'm trying to pass when I add a new user to my table column. I can successfully add a user but I'm trying to reset my redux state with the new user that has just been added.

Inside my object contains the below values.

[image]

I'm trying to add a user into my tables column however, when I click on my add user submit button, I get this error shown below.

output of

> console.log(this.props.isFetchingUsers, providerAccount.id);

[image]

> *TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined*

[image]

I pretty just want if the user clicks on the button, it adds the user to the redux state. It works right now when I refresh the window and automatically adds ONLY when its refreshed so I'm assuming I have to do something with my reducers.

[image]

Component js file

```
    const fetchUsers = this.props.isFetchingUsers[providerAccount.id];

    const fetchEmails = fetchUsers.map(values => {
        return values.user.emailAddress;
    });

    const fetchUsersDetails = fetchUsers.map(values => {
        return {
            accessLevel: values.accessLevel,
            emailAddress: values.user.emailAddress,
            userName: values.user.userName
        };
    });
```

Dispatch (same file)

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
    getUsersForMyProviderAccount: () => dispatch(getUsersForMyProviderAccount())
});

const WrappedUsersList = Form.create()(UsersList);

export default connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    mapDispatchToProps
)(WrappedUsersList);
```

Action JS file

```
export function addUserAccessToMyProviderAccountSuccess(params) {
    return {
        type: ADD_USER_ACCESS_TO_MY_PROVIDER_ACCOUNT_SUCCESS,
        params
    };
}
```

Reducers JS file

```
case UPDATE_USER_ACCESS_TO_MY_PROVIDER_ACCOUNT_SUCCESS:
        case ADD_USER_ACCESS_TO_MY_PROVIDER_ACCOUNT_SUCCESS: {
            const { payload = [], usersForProviderAccounts = {} } = params;
            console.log(payload);
            return {
                ...store,
                isFetching: false,
                usersForProviderAccounts
            };
        }
```

Comment: so `fetch` is undefined. We have no clue where you defined it, so hard to help.

Comment: @epascarello [`fetch()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API)?

Comment: No `const fetch = this.props.isFetchingUsers[providerAccount.id];` is undefined, so your problem is....

Comment: @epascarello I thought that cannot be redefined.

Comment: I've changed the fetch to fetchUser. Same error

Comment: @PraveenKumarPurushothaman nothing prevents you from overriding it.

Comment: Wow... @ArthurTruong Is it an AJAX call? Asynchronous call?

Comment: @epascarello Got it.

Comment: So debug and see why `console.log(this.props.isFetchingUsers, providerAccount.id)`

Comment: @epascarello fetchUsers grabs all the objects inside that array (which works). providerAccount.id just returns the id for that user.

Comment: @ArthurTruong Is it possible to create a [mcve] using https://CodeSandbox.io?

Comment: @ArthurTruong So.... you are reading it when something is not defined so debug. The console statement will show you. So my guess is you are trying to read a property that is asynchronously loaded and you are expecting it to be there. So you need to add a check if it is not set, than skip it.

Comment: what is the output of `console.log(this.props.isFetchingUsers, providerAccount.id, fetchUsers)`

Comment: @MarkusDresch I've added the picture of the output to my post.

Comment: could it simply be a type error? you are passing a string `"1"` as index, when a number is expected.

Comment: I have a feeling the console is telling a fib. What is: `console.log(JSON.stingify(this.props.isFetchingUsers))`

Comment: @epascarello TypeError: JSON.stingify is not a function

Comment: guessing you did not spot my typo... st**r**ingify

Comment: @epascarello returns pretty much all my objects into strings. (same thing just stringified)